# converting function to jquery click() call

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the code that I'm trying to convert:

```
<script>
function fsomething(rowid) {
   window.location = "/somewhere/" + rowid;
}

</script>
<tr>
  <td>
      <button onClick="fsomething('{{rowid}}')">row 1L</button>
  </td>
  <td>
      <button onClick="fsomething('{{rowid}}')">row 2L</button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

How can I convert this to:

```
$('button').click(function() { .... } );
```

where `{{rowid}}` is dynamically generated, and unique to each row?

Comment: How do you want to get the row id from a td?

Comment: What generates the HTML, is this a jQuery template, PHP, ...? If you can change your html output to be something like `<button data-rowId="{{rowid}}"` this would be very easy.

Comment: Any reason why you cannot use `<a href="..."><button>row 1L</button></a>` or alike? Users with JS disabled cannot use your website in your way.

Comment: I put some grammar into your question to make it look more professional. Also, you should put `type="text/javascript" in your `script` tag, and your `table` structure is incomplete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you store the id using a `data-` attribute then you can get that out of the element when it is clicked.

```
<script>

$(function(){

    $("td button").click(function(e){

        // Go to the URL
        window.location = "/somewhere/" + $(this).data("rowid");

        // Prevent default action if any
        e.preventDefault();

    });

});

</script>

<tr>
    <td>
        <button data-rowid="{{rowid}}">row 1L</button>
    </td>
    <td>
        <button data-rowid="{{rowid}}">row 2L</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Though I'm not sure if moving the location of the rowid is feasible yet, I do agree and think this is the best-fit solution. (Though the [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method would be a better fit, IMHO.)

Comment: Yes, these methods fit better. I always use attr out of habit which I should try to curb I guess.

Comment: Just be cauitious, data-attributes is HTML5 specific. IE < 9 will not understand this

Comment: This code will work on IE < 9, data-attributes aren't officially supported by these versions but they will still parse the attributes and you can get them using jQuery or without using `getAttribute`.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably change the buttons to something like this:

```
<button id="{{rowid}}">row 1L</button>
```

And then use jQuery something like this:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    window.location = "/somewhere/" + $(this).attr("id");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

possible solution

```
$('button').click(function(event))
{
window.location = "/somewhere/" + $(event.target).attr('id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the {{row id}} to each button as an attribute and then read it in the method:

```
<button rowid="{{rowid}}">row 1L</button>

$('button').click(function() { fsomething($(this).attr("rowid")); } );
```